# How to switch tab in cuprite and assert content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, cuprite

I'm using cuprite 0.13
Capybara 3.53.3
Rspec 3.11

I have a simple spec that clicks on the link with `target="_blank"` attribute.

```rb
      new_window = page.window_opened_by do
        click_on "Link with target blank"
      end

# I'm trying to test it capybara way

      within_window(new_window) do
        expect(page).to have_text("Some text")
      end
```

But getting this error

```
Ferrum::JavaScriptError (ReferenceError: _cuprite is not defined)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:15)
```

Switch manually procudes same error `page.driver.browser.switch_to_window(new_window.handle)`

Comment: Seems like a cuprite bug, try sleeping for a second or two to give the new tab time to load

Comment: @ThomasWalpole didn't help. tried even 15 seconds. Looks like cuprite is not loaded in tab at all.

Comment: I’d recommend filing an issue on the cuprite driver project then

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with cuprite (0.14.3) & capybara (~> 3.0):

```rb
page.driver.browser.switch_to_window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)
```

Cf. [switch_to_window](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cuprite/0.8/Capybara/Cuprite/Browser#switch_to_window-instance_method)